# active directory users functionality disappeared after windows 10 anniversary update

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, updates

After windows 10 anniversary update and windows 10 creators update
the active directory users and computers functionality disappeared
and there was no way to re-activate it.
Downloading and re-installing WindowsTH-RSAT_WS_1709-x64.msu had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by uninstalling KB2693643 and then installing WindowsTH-RSAT_WS_1709-x64.msu again:

Control panel, Programs, see installed updates, select KB2693643, uninstall

download RSAT_WS_1709-x64.msu from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45520

run RSAT_WS_1709-x64.msu, agree to install KB2693643, accept license, restart computer

P.S. Hope this may help somebody. Of course use x32 version if you have no x64 computer

Comment: With further versions of Windows 10 (1803, 1809, 1903) the AD users function still disappears, but I do not need to uninstall KB2693643, it is enough to install TH-RSAT again.

With 1809 and 1903 there was no matching version of TH-RSAT available. So I chose the 1803 version and it worked.